# Why Pesucha between Lo Sisa and Zachor Es HaShabbos?

Tags: mesorah-tradition, parashas-yisro, aseres-hadibros

In the Aseres HaDibros in Yisro, why is there Pesucha at the end of Lo Sisa and before Zachor Es HaShabbos, while the rest are separated by stumos?

**Edit**: Besides being out of place in Yisro, In V'Eschnon the entire Aseres HaDibros has just Stumos even between Lo Sisa and Shamor Es Yom HaShabbos?

Comment: Perhaps through Lo Sisa (2 Parshiyot) was said by God, and from Zachor on (8 Parshiyot) was said by Moshe, in accordance with the Midrash that the first 2 of the 10 were said by God directly.

Comment: @DoubleAA The first part till the Pesucha contain 3 Dibros Anochi, Lo Yeheh and Lo Sisa not just the two said by G-d. However, the first Stuma does contain the first 2 Dibros which may possibly hint to the fact they were said together by G-d.

Comment: There are multiple ways of splitting up the Dibrot (see [here](http://www.torah.org/advanced/mikra/5757/sh/dt.57.2.05.html#)). You refer to the counting as set forth in the Taam Elyon. There are other ways of splitting it up, such as by the 10 Parshiyot which indicates a different way of counting 10 commandments.

Comment: @DoubleAA Where do we see a reference to 2 Parshiyos were said, I am only familiar with the Gemurah in Makos 23b-24a which says  "אנכי ולא יהיה לך מפי הגבורה שמענום" ?

Comment: I don't have one (though it's perfectly plausible, and the split into 10 Parshiyot is undeniable), but the fact that the Bavli (from the place of origin of the Taam Elyon) uses those examples shouldn't preclude the existance of variant Midrashim of the same type. Just like how the Bavli says that the Samekh in the Luchot floated miraculously, but the Yerushalmi has a variant that says it was the Ayin (because in Ketav Ivri the Ayin looks like a circle). In other words, don't be wedded to the Bavli's example when approaching the Midrash.

Answer (score 3):

Both sets of Dibros start off אנכי יהוה אלהיך אשר **הוצאתיך מארץ מצרים** מבית עבדים לא יהיה לך אלהים אחרים על פני, the basis of our general obligation to believe in and follow Hashems laws is He took us out of Egypt.

The next time a basis for keeping a Mitzvah is given is Shabbos זכור את יום השבת לקדשו...**כי ששת ימים עשה יהוה את השמים ואת הארץ** את הים ואת כל אשר בם וינח ביום השביעי על כן ברך יהוה את יום השבת ויקדשהו, in Yisro we are to keep because Hashem created the world in 6 days and rested on the seventh, however, in V'Eschnon it says **וזכרת כי עבד היית בארץ מצרים ויצאך** יהוה אלהיך משם ביד חזקה ובזרע נטויה על כן צוך יהוה אלהיך לעשות את יום השבת, since He took us out of Egypt He is commanding us to "make" the Day Of Shabbos.

In Yisro which Shabbos is presented as based on מעשה בראשית unlike the previous Dibros it is, unlike the rest of the Dibros, preceded by a Pesucha, a new paragraph, so to speak. In V'Eschnon, however, which Shabbos is also based on יציאת מצרים a Pesucha is not needed and a Stumah is used.

Rabbi Y. Yoffee - Monsey, NY

Comment: I want to thank my relative in Monsey who got this for me.

Comment: Like a separate inyan.